# django set client encoding with multiple database

Tags: django, postgresql

Buenas estoy desarrollando una `API` mediante `django rest framework` y para ello tengo configuradas dos bases de datos. Necesito hacer una `query` a la segunda base de datos configurada **(postgresql)** y consigo que me devuelva los datos pero me los da con los caracteres especiales sin decodificar. Por ejemplo para la palabra **"matemáticas"** me devuelve `"Matem\u00e1ticas"`.

He probado a hacer una consulta fuera del entorno de `django` y mediante el método `conn.set_client_encoding('UTF8')` se soluciona el problema pero en `django` no encuentro ningún método parecido. Adjunto el código con el que me funciona fuera de `django`:

```
import psycopg2

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='XXX' user='XXX' host='XXX' password='XXX'")
except:
    print("No ha sido posible conectar a la base de datos")

conn.set_client_encoding('UTF8')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""XXX""")
rows = cur.fetchall()
...
```

Y así es como establezco conexión con la base de datos en `django`

```
conn = connections['XXX']
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""XXX""")
rows = cur.fetchall()
...
```

¿Habría algún equivalente en `django` a `conn.set_client_encoding('UTF8')`?

Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme y gracias.

Comment: Una consulta Alberto ya configuraste el UTF8 en postgresql?

Comment: La base de datos es externa no tengo permiso ni acceso a la configuración

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionar este problema edite el archivo de configuración de python pero como dices que no puedes acceder a la base de datos tendras que pedir que lo haga el administrador de la base de datos.

**EN PYTHON 2.6**
/usr/lib/python2.6/site.py en la linea 456 donde dice:

456: encoding = “ascii”# Default value set by _PyUnicode_Init()

Cambiamos por:
456: encoding = “utf-8”# Default value set by _PyUnicode_Init()

**EN PYTHON 2.7**
/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py en la linea 493 donde dice:

493: encoding = “ascii”# Default value set by _PyUnicode_Init()

Cambiamos por:
493: encoding = “utf-8”# Default value set by _PyUnicode_Init()